# When I do print(True), does the printed value count as a string or a boolean?

Tags: python

If I run a function that returns true or false, 
and I do

```
print(that_function(x))
```

Then when it is true, True is printed out and if false, False is printed out.
Are these boolean values being shown on screen, or string that are being printed using the print function?

Comment: Technically it is a string once it is printed. The `print` statement turns it to a `str` then prints it to terminal

Comment: [Read the docs and research your own question first](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) - "All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream"

Comment: Some signal which can interpret by python, as Boolean True or False and that particular signal interpret by print function to your screen by lighting up some pixels in your screen as the way you can understand what it is by your eyes.

In my understanding your question is like when you think "yes" or "no" from your brain, whether the same comes from your mouth :)

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your function is `bool`. Indeed when simply typing:

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
```

But when you use the built-in `print` method, behind the scenes the arguments of `print` are converted to strings. And so what is actually being printed is the string `"True"`.

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> **print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)**
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and
>   written to the stream, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*. Both *sep*
>   and *end* must be strings; they can also be `None`, which means to use the
>   default values. If no *objects* are given, `print()` will just write *end*.

Comment: Ah, thank you! So kind of like how print(1) prints out the string "1" and not the int?

Comment: yes that's true for all types. you can even play with it by creating your own class and implementing the `__str__` function and see what you get